# Jenkins build failing due to Checkmarx despite increasing Java heap space

Tags: java, jenkins, jenkins-plugins, heap-memory, sast

My Jenkins build is failing after retrieving the SAST scan results from the [Checkmarx Plugin](https://www.jenkins.io/doc/pipeline/steps/checkmarx/).

```
[Cx-Info]: Waiting for SAST scan results. Elapsed time: 00:43:26. 99% processed. Status: Finished.  
[Cx-Info]: SAST scan finished successfully.  
[Cx-Info]: Retrieving SAST scan results  
FATAL: Java heap space  
java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space  
    at org.apache.commons.io.IOUtils.byteArray(IOUtils.java:338)
```

I have already tried increasing the xmx significantly up to `-Xmx2g`.  UPDATE: I have also tried 3GB:

```
Checking if Java is installed by asking for version.  
Java Source: DETECT_JAVA_PATH=C:\Program Files (x86)\Jenkins\jre\bin\java.exe  
Java Standard Output: Error occurred during initialization of VM  
Could not reserve enough space for 2097152KB object heap  

Java Error Output: Picked up JAVA_TOOL_OPTIONS: -Xms256m -Xmx2g
```

I rebooted Jenkins by appending /safeRestart to the URL.  All of this continued to result in the error persisting.  Are there any other solutions to this or do I need to add even more memory?